# How to finish a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm doing an APP with a login system, and now I have a problem when I'm logged, when I enter the credentials, I replace the fragment with another interface, but If user press the back button, the app come back to the login screen (fragment). I want to know how to remove the login screen if the user has logged in.

I change the fragments with:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction_to_main = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction_to_main.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.modal_in, R.anim.modal_out);
                transaction_to_main.replace(R.id.container, new MainFragment());
                transaction_to_main.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction_to_main.commit();
```

I'm trying to use this part of code that I have read in the forum to clear the backstack, but I get a NullPointerException

```
while (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
                    getFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
                }
```

Thank you

EDIT:

In a main activity, in onCreate:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null || shared_pref.contains("access_token")){
            shared_pref_token = shared_pref.getString("access_token", "");
            shared_pref_refresh_token = shared_pref.getString("refresh_token", "");

            //Check if token is valid, if not, a new token is requested
            check_token(shared_pref_token);

        }else{
            iv_logout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.modal_in, R.anim.modal_out);
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, new AccessFragment());
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
            //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setTransition(R.anim.modal_in).replace(R.id.container, new AccessFragment()).commit();
        }
```

The AccessFragment has in the onCreate:

```
bt_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.modal_in, R.anim.modal_out);
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, new LoginFragment());
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getTargetFragment()).commit();
                /*new SweetAlertDialog(getActivity(), SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE)
                        .setTitleText("Sesión iniciada en GECAS")
                        .show();*/
            }
        });

        bt_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.modal_in, R.anim.modal_out);
                transaction.replace(R.id.container, new RegisterFragment());
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(getTargetFragment()).commit();
            }
        });
```

Comment: how did you add login fragment, could you show your code?

Comment: you don't need addToBackStack() method, you should remove it and run again. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the line with addToBackStack

```
transaction_to_main.addToBackStack(null);
```

it shouldn't get added to the backstack in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Is the right way to clear your backstack.

Comment: "Call requires API LEVEL 11", my minimun requeriments is 9. :(

Comment: You can use getSupportFragmentManager which you can find in support lib.

Answer (score 0):

As some patterns says, removing the line transaction.addToBackStack(null) solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

on activity

```
finish();
```

on fragment

```
getActivity().finish();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. SO is about learning too.

Comment: Please enhance your answer.

Comment: This closes the activity, not fragment